# Quest: How can I place the gas sensors?

Tags: starfield

I was asked to place 7 gas sensors in (or around) a little settler camp. Unfortunately I have several problems with it

1. I don't see any gas sensors in my inventory and I can't find such sensors near the quest giving NPC and I can't buy in the local shop
2. I can't find the gas spots mentioned. Are these sensors for machines? Or for some natural gas erupting spots?
3. I cannot interact with possible targets like the fuming little 'volcanoes'.

As soon as I jump or travel to another planet, the quest is lost and remains unsolved (red cross). What I have to do to exactly to solve this quest?

[image]

Comment: Is there a name for this quest?

Comment: @TimmyJim - I play the German version and it is called "Dampfanalyse" (on the planet Procyion III). I assume it is something like Steam-/Vapour-Analysis. I should place sensors on different locations in the vicinity.

Comment: Mark the quest as active in the quest log, go to the blue dots and interact with the gas vent, and it'll place a sensor. They are not items in your inventory.

Comment: @Neon1024 - Unfortunately there are absolutely no blue dots, no "follow me" trace on the ground or any other hint where I should go.

Comment: Do you remember where picked up the quest? I havent done it yet, so I can try picking up the quest to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Dragonrage - After reading a lot of articles about this topic in the meantime, this quest seems to occure randomly. I got mine on Procyion III, but others got it elsewhere. It is a side quest. (I try to add a picture to my initial question).

Comment: There is a game bug right now where quest markers can break and not show, or show for a different quest. Try restarting the game and see if the quest markers come back.

Comment: I also tried with an earlier savegame and got the quest from another NPC in the same settlement. Unfortunately, also without blue dots or hints to the 7 targets. @Mufasa seems to be right with the bug...